# Variable length in Xamarin Community Toolkit MaskedBehavior

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I'm trying to use the Xamarin Community Toolkit `MaskedBehavior` in my app for phone extensions which can be 2, 3 or even up to 6 digits long.

It's easy to define the mask if it's a set length but how do I use it in this case where I want the user to enter only numeric values but the length can be anywhere from 2 to 6 digits?

```
<Entry
    Placeholder="Ext"
    Text="{Binding Extension}"
    Keyboard="Numeric">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
       <xct:MaskedBehavior
           Mask="X?????"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

Comment: I've never used this, but seems to me the underlying question is "How do I indicate to the user that the length can be anywhere from 2 to 6 digits"? If the Mask isn't capable of doing that, you'll have to do it some other way. Maybe as each character is entered, check whether they've entered minimum. If so, show a button they use if done with that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I don't have to do anything. When I set the mask as `Mask="XXXXXX"`, it will accept any number of digits up to 6. It doesn't force the user to always enter six digits.